# How can I get the max value from one column where values match another column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large dataframe where one column has a set of names in it. Unfortunately, the same column also has some other data there. What I want to do is to find all the rows that contain the names, look for those in another column, get the max value from a third column. Then, I need to place that value in the same row as the name.

I'm currently using a `for` loop, which does exactly what I want, but it is extremely slow. I've tried fooling around with `lookup` but can't get it to work. Just bear in mind that the real dataframe has something like 20,000 rows!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

friends = ['Mickey', 'Minnie', 'Goofy', 'Donald', 'Daisy', 'Pluto']

df_data = {'Name':['Mickey', 'Ravens', 'Vikings',
                    'Minnie', 'Packers', 'Browns',
                    'Goofy', 'Cowboys', 'Steelers',
                    'Donald', '49ers', 'Bears',
                    'Daisy', 'Chiefs', 'Raiders',
                    'Pluto', 'Patriots', 'Colts'],
        'Owner': [np.nan, 'Mickey', 'Mickey',
                    np.nan, 'Minnie', 'Minnie', 
                    np.nan, 'Goofy', 'Goofy', 
                    np.nan, 'Donald', 'Donald',
                    np.nan, 'Daisy', 'Daisy',
                    np.nan, 'Pluto', 'Pluto'],
        'Wins': [np.nan, 14, 10,
                np.nan, 13, 6,
                np.nan, 8, 8,
                np.nan, 13, 8,
                np.nan, 12, 7,
                np.nan, 12, 7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = df_data)

for f in friends:
    df.loc[df['Name'] == f, 'Wins'] = df.loc[df['Owner'] == f, 'Wins'].max()

print(df.to_string())
```

Comment: I feel like this would be a combination of `isin()` and `groupby`?

Comment: @sammywemmy: the MRE gives my expected output, I'm just trying to avoid the for loop

Comment: oh ok. my bad. seems someone has attempted it

Comment: @CeliusStingher, I played with that, but couldn't figure out how to avoid the loop still. I'm sure I'll feel dumb when someone posts a simple groupby that I should have thought of, but I've been stuck on this for two days!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use

```
df['Wins'].update(df['Name'].map(df.groupby('Owner')['Wins'].max()))
```

Comment: Where are you using `friends`?

Comment: @Sheldore I don't really need to because they are also encoded in the Owner column.

Comment: This is both the simplest and faster method. I ran a `timeit` w/ 100 trials and this clocked in at about 1.04 seconds vs. about 1.7 for @Shubham-Sharma and about 2.15 for @Sayandip-Dutta

Answer (score 1):

Use, [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `Owner` then use the `agg` function `max` to create a mapping series `s`, Now using the series `s` update the values in `Wins` column in `df` using [`Series.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html):

```
s = df.groupby('Owner')['Wins'].max()
df = df.set_index('Name')
df['Wins'].update(s)
df = df.reset_index()
```

---

```
# print(df)
        Name   Owner  Wins
0     Mickey     NaN  14.0
1     Ravens  Mickey  14.0
2    Vikings  Mickey  10.0
3     Minnie     NaN  13.0
4    Packers  Minnie  13.0
5     Browns  Minnie   6.0
6      Goofy     NaN   8.0
7    Cowboys   Goofy   8.0
8   Steelers   Goofy   8.0
9     Donald     NaN  13.0
10     49ers  Donald  13.0
11     Bears  Donald   8.0
12     Daisy     NaN  12.0
13    Chiefs   Daisy  12.0
14   Raiders   Daisy   7.0
15     Pluto     NaN  12.0
16  Patriots   Pluto  12.0
17     Colts   Pluto   7.0
```